# Cambiar formato de datetimerpicker a yyyy/mm/dd de tipo DateTime en c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

en este codigo solo estoy mostrando la fecha dd/mm/yyyy

```
datetime fecha = dateTimePickerFalta.Value.Date
```

quiero obtenerlo en yyyy/mm/dd pero de tipo dateTime

como lo puedo hacer ?

ejemplo:

cuendo selecciono una fecha el formato que me muestra es

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

la utilizare para hacer una consulta a access que me acepta solo el formato de

```
yyyy/mm/dd
```

este es mi codigo completo donde hago consulta a la base de datos que me pide el formato de yyyy/mm/dd:

```
private void Reporte()
        {
            string query = @"select 
                                p.cod, 
                                p.tipo, 
                                p.nombre
                            from Persona p where not exists( 
                                select ma.cod 
                                from Marcaciones ma where 
                                ma.cod = p.cod
                                and (fecha =@fecha) 
                                and (grado = @grado) 
                                and (p.paralelo = @paralelo)";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grado", cmbTipoPersona.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paralelo", cmbParalelo.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dateTimePickerFalta.Value);

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            DataSetReporte.Clear();

            adapter.Fill(DataSetReporte, "DTFaltas");    /////// ERROR: No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.  
            dataGridView.DataSource = DataSetReporte;
            dataGridView.DataMember = "DTFaltas";
            dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**de esta manera access lo acepta y funciona como quiero**

```
select 
                                p.cod, 
                                p.tipo, 
                                p.nombre
                            from Persona p where not exists( 
                                select ma.cod 
                                from Marcaciones ma where 
                                ma.cod = p.cod
                                and (fecha = fecha  = #2017/11/09# ) 
                                and (grado = @grado) 
                                and (p.paralelo = @paralelo)
```

Comment: Agrega más información, un ejemplo del formato que deseas cambiar, mm se aplica para minutos, para indicar mes, se usa la M mayúscula.

Comment: *quiero obtenerlo en yyyy/mm/dd pero de tipo dateTime*:  Lo que pides no tiene sentido. El tipo `DateTime` no tiene formato. Si quieres un formato específico, debes convertir la fecha a un `string`.

Comment: edite la pregunta, es el access que me esta pidiento el formato y la hice con una query en access y funciona muy bien, el formato string como lo utilizo en mi consulta?

Comment: No estoy convencido de que hayas identificado bien la causa de tu problema. Por favor expande la sección de detalles de tu error e inclúyelo a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver esto con [tag:.htaccess]? Elimino esa etiqueta.

Answer (score -1):

Revisando tu actualización, aplica el formato al obtener el dato del dateTimePicker, ejemplo:

```
string nuevoFormato =  dateTimePickerFalta.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

En tu código:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dateTimePickerFalta.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Comment: eso es sierto, la idea es la de llegar a DateTime

Comment: @R.Fernandez He editado mi respuesta con la información que agregaste, DateTime no, sería string para realizar :  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dateTimePickerFalta.Value); .

Comment: lo e intentado de la manera que pone aqui :                                           
string nuevoFormato = dateTimePickerFalta.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaFalta", nuevoFormato);                                     e igual me sale el error de los formatos

Comment: El error se produce cuando ejecutas el query ?

Comment: el error se produce cuando en la consula al tratar de comparar la fecha

Comment: @El error es porque intentas comparar un campo de tipo DateTime con un string.
Si @fecha te da el valor ("2017/11/20 0:00:00") lo puedes comparar con :

`DateTime nuevoFormato = DateTime.ParseExact(fechaDateTimePicker, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", nuevoFormato));`